# JAVA: How to automatically write unique ID number to a .CSV file

Tags: java, csv, io

I'm doing a java desktop application which writes "ID, Name, Address, Phone number" into a .CSV file then reads and shows it on JTable. The problem is ID needs to be a unique Integer number that automatically written. Every time you write, it must not be the same as any number of the previous written IDs. I tried creating a method that increases ID number by 1 for every time you click a button. But if you exit the program and run again, the ID number starts from 0 as I initialized it to.

Edit: I'm new to programming.

Comment: you could use a timestamp. That way the output will be unique unless you run more than one copy of the program at the same time.

Comment: Must it be an `int`? Would a long work? If a long works, the current time in milliseconds might work depending. UUID is my usual go to for such things. You could potentially store the last written value in a file and read it in at program launch.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I'll try both of this

Comment: provide more details..like whether it would be multi-threaded or not...possible datat types for ID etc.

Comment: I used timeStamp to achieve this but the problem is, ID is still not unique. I tested running my app and wrote 2 data into my CSV file ended up having 2 same ID numbers. I think this is because timeStamp gets the time exactly while I ran my app?

Comment: Have you tried `System.nanoTime()`? or You can try `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`.

Comment: By the way, it doesn't need to be an  Integer. But smaller the better

Comment: @AshfordTulgaa which method did you use for timestamp?

Comment: String id = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new java.util.Date());

Comment: Don't use this one. As, it goes maximum to milliseconds..if a single thread is in use, go to System.nanoTime()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The best option is to use out-of-the box solution: Use
  [UUID.randomUUID()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID--) method. It gives you a unique id.
- Second option: You will have to write your last used ID into persistent storage (File, DB or other option). So when your program starts you read your last used ID and generate the next value. This way you can use numeric sequence. If Thread safety is an issue you can use class [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) to store your value. (But it won't help if you run your app twice as two separate processes)
- Third: Use the timestamp you can get it as Long. (simple solution, no tracking previous values needed)

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two approaches to this:

1. Use a UUID:

   - UUIDs are big random numbers. There is a chance that you'll get the same
      one twice, but the probability is so low as to be negligible, because
      the number space is so unimaginably huge
   - get one with `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`
2. Use an atomic identifier source.

   - This is just something with a lock to prevent concurrent access, that
      emits unique numbers on request

A very simple identifier generator uses `synchronized` to ensure atomicity:

```
public class UniqueIdGenerator {

     private long currentId;

     public UniqueGenerator(long startingId) {
        this.currentId = startingId;
     }

     public synchronized int getUniqueId() {
         return currentId++;
     }
}
```

(You can also use `AtomicLong`, or let a database engine take care of atomicity for you)

There are more advanced strategies for making this work in a distributed system -- for example, the generator could be accessible as a web service. But this is probably beyond the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist the last written ID and there are many different ways you could think of.

1. Writing ID to a file
2. Writing ID to User-Preferences (maybe a windows-registry entry?)

You have to think of the uniqnes of the ID. What if you run the programm as two different users on the same machine? What if you run your programm on two different machines?

Comment: The ultimate question is what constitutes uniqueness -- globally, on a machine, in a directory, etc.

Comment: @KevinO Yes, you are right. I would ask for WHO want´s to have this uniqenes and WHY (for what).

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your application and everytime you manipulate (write)  your .csv file. You could update your ID to start from the max(ID's in your .csv) and then add 1 everytime you create a new entry.

You might consider using a small embedded Database (e.g Apache derby) and not writing .csv files. That might be a "cleaner" solution because you can use Database operations to ensure that behaviour.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

If ID is required in long format and environment is not multi-threaded then `System.nanoTime()` can be used.

Otherwise for multi-threaded environments, there could be multiple solutions:

1. `java.security.SecureRandom`
2. `java.util.UUID.randomUUID`--> internally uses `SecureRandom`
3. `File.createTempFile().getName()` --> internally use `SecureRandom`

If a long output is required then `String.hashCode()` can be used after above code.